# Find M Arithmetic Sequences of N elements in a List containing M*N shuffled elements

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sequence

**Question:**
M arithmetic progressions each having N terms (with the terms differing by d1,d2,...dm) are passed as input with the terms shuffled. The program must print the terms in M arithmetic progressions in sequential order with the smallest starting term first.

**Input Format:**
The first line contains the value of M
The second line contains the terms separated by space (The number of terms will be M*N)

**Boundary Conditions:**
2 <= M <= 5
N >= 3

**Output Format:**
The terms in the progressions (each separated by a space) in sequential order with the progression having the smallest starting term appearing first.

**Example Input/Output 1:**

Input:

```
2
1 4 8 12 7 16
```

Output:

```
1 4 7 8 12 16
```

*Explanation:*

```
There are two progressions. Hence 6/2 = 3 terms in each progression.
So the first A.M has 1 4 7 and the second has 8 12 16
As 1 < 8, 1 4 7 is printed followed by 8 12 16
```

**Example Input/Output 2:**

Input:

```
3
2 6 8 10 15 22 12 11 4
```

Output:

```
2 4 6 8 15 22 10 11 12
```

*Explanation:*

```
There are three progressions. Hence 9/3 = 3 terms in each progression.
So the first A.M has 2 4 6 and the second has 8 15 22. The third has 10 11 12.
```

**Note:** We cannot have 8 10 12 as the second progression as the remaining numbers 11 15 22 do not for an arithmetic progression.

**Example Input/Output 3:**

Input:

```
4
20 24 28 32 41 46 51 50 60 90 10 170 70 36 40 250
```

Output:

```
10 90 170 250 20 24 28 32 36 41 46 51 40 50 60 70
```

**Example Input/Output 4:**

Input:

```
3
180 66 100 44 120 55 60 400 200 300 33 240
```

Output:

```
33 44 55 66 60 120 180 240 100 200 300 400
```

**My Code (so far):**

```
from __future__ import division
from itertools import permutations

m=int(raw_input())
values=map(int,raw_input().split())
terms=len(values)/m
permutation=list(permutations(values,terms))
lst=[]
for i in range(m):
    for perm in permutation:
        mean=sum(perm)/len(perm)
        temp=list(sorted(perm))
        if temp in lst:
            continue
        if len(perm)%2==0:
            med=(temp[int((len(temp)/2)-1)]+temp[int(len(temp)/2)])/2
            if med==mean:
                lst+=[temp]
        else:
            med=temp[int(len(temp)/2)]
            if med==mean:
                lst+=[temp]
lst=sorted(lst,key=lambda x:x[0])
print lst
```

I am able to list all possible arithmetic sequences in the given input but  have no idea how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def explore(n, terms, seqs):

    if not terms:  # if all terms have been processed, you found a solution
        return {tuple(sum(sorted(seqs), []))}

    result = set()

    for ix, seq in enumerate(seqs):

        new_seqs = list(seqs)
        new_seqs[ix] = seq + [terms[0]]

        if len(seq) == 0:  # if you are adding to an empty sequence
            if ix == 0 or len(seqs[ix - 1]) > 0:  # be sure previous is not empty
                result.update(explore(n, terms[1:], new_seqs))
            break  # don't bother checking following seqs, they are empty

        elif len(seq) == 1:  # you can always add to 1-element seq
            result.update(explore(n, terms[1:], new_seqs))

        elif len(seq) < n and seq[-1] * 2 == seq[-2] + terms[0]:  # is arithmetic?
            result.update(explore(n, terms[1:], new_seqs))

    return result

m = int(raw_input())
terms = sorted(map(int, raw_input().split()))
seqs = [[] for _ in range(m)]

result = explore(len(terms) / m, terms, seqs)

for solution in result:
    print(" ".join(map(str, solution)))
```

Here is a (incomplete) solution, which should help you. The idea is that you create the division of terms into sequences `seqs` (initially empty) and try to put terms in ascending order into one of the seqs so that

1. each seq is an arithmetic sequence
2. first elements of seqs are in ascending order
3. all empty seqs are after all non-empty seqs

Comment: I have not studied Backtracking so could u explain this solution a bit more ?

Comment: You don't need to have studied backtracking to understand it. Put some print statements inside `explore` to see how it works.

Comment: The code is returning multiple results for a test case. Could u explain why ? And Is it possible to get the output as a list instead of printing it directly ? **Failing Input Testcase :** `3, 
100 150 100 200 300 500 900 100 1700 250 700 2500`

Comment: It returned may solutions, because the problem specification did not state which of `1 2 3 1 11 21` and `1 11 21 1 2 3` is expected for input `2\n 1 1 2 3 11 21`. I changed the code so that it chooses the the first in lexicographical order.

Answer (score 1):

You could use itertools.combinations with a Counter dict sorting the list in descending order:

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter
def arith_seq(l, m):
    l.sort(reverse=True)
    terms = len(l) // m
    combs = filter(lambda x: all((x[i + 1] - x[i] == x[1] - x[0]
                                       for i in range(len(x) - 1))), combinations(l, terms))
    out = []
    cn = Counter(l)
    for ele in combs:
        if all(cn[c] > 0 for c in ele):
            out.append(ele[::-1])
            for c in ele:
                cn[c] -= 1
    out.sort()
    return out
```

Output:

```
In [15]: ms = [2, 3, 4, 3, 3]
In [16]: for l, m in zip(lsts, ms):
            print(arith_seq(l, m))
   ....:     
[(1, 4, 7), (8, 12, 16)]
[(2, 4, 6), (8, 15, 22), (10, 11, 12)]
[(10, 90, 170, 250), (20, 24, 28, 32), (36, 41, 46, 51), (40, 50, 60, 70)]
[(33, 44, 55, 66), (60, 120, 180, 240), (100, 200, 300, 400)]
[(100, 150, 200, 250), (100, 300, 500, 700), (100, 900, 1700, 2500)]
```

Comment: This doesn't give the correct answer. It gives only 2 of the possible combinations.

Comment: @DarthShadow, what two combinations?

Comment: **Failing Input Testcase :**   `3, 100 150 100 200 300 500 900 100 1700 250 700 2500`

Comment: Where is the question from?

Comment: The output must be : `[[100, 150, 200, 250], [100, 300, 500, 700], [100, 900, 1700, 2500]]`

Answer (score 0):

I have an algorithm with time complexity less than `O(180 mn)`.

At first, sort the sequence in ascending order. Then

```
explore(n, m, terms, seqs)
    if m == 0 you find a solution seqs and sort seqs by its first terms. return;
    enumerate 2 elements a, b from the first m+1 elements of terms:
        if there exist a arithmetic sequence S whose first two terms are a, b and length is n:
           explore(n, m - 1, terms - S, seqs + [S])
```

This algorithm is based on an effect that first `m+1` elements of the sorted sequence must contain first two terms of one arithmetic sequence.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void FormingArray(int a, int b, int n, int arr[])
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = a + (i * b);
    }
}
void PrintingArray(int n, int arr[])
{
    cout<<"The array is: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout <<"No."<<(i+1)<<" "<< arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
int SubArray(int arr[] , int n) //Sigma Series
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
    
}
int firstNegItem(int arr[],int n) //First Negative Item
{
    int i = 0;
        while(arr[i]>0)
        {
            i++;
            if (arr[i]<0)
            break;
        }
    return(arr[i+1]);
}
int firstPosItem(int arr[],int n) //First Positive Item
{
        int i = 0;
        while(arr[i]<0)
        {
            i++;
            if (arr[i]>0)
            break;
        }
    return(arr[i+1]);
}
void credit() { cout<<"This program is made by Ali Alsaeid \nThanks for choosing this program <3 \n"; }
int main()
{
    int a; //The First Item
    int b; //Array's Base
    int n; //Number of Items
    int* arr = new int(n); //Sizing Array
    cout << "Enter a (First Item), b (Array's Base), n (Number of Items) \n";
    //Input
    cin >> a >> b >> n;
    FormingArray(a,b,n,arr);
    //Output
    PrintingArray(n,arr); 
    cout << "Submission Array is " << SubArray(arr, n) << endl; //Sigma series
    if (b<0 && a>0)
        cout<<"The first negative item is: "<<firstNegItem(arr,n)<<endl;
    else if (b>0 && a<0)
        cout<<"The first positive item is: "<<firstPosItem(arr,n)<<endl;
    credit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might be a bit more helpful if your answer added a couple of comments/lines describing how/why your answer works!

Comment: what do you want me to explain exactly?